# What's the purpose of HashMap.Entry.recordAccess and recordRemoval?

Tags: java

If you take a look at the code for HashMap, you'll find empty methods called recordAccess and recordRemoval. What's the purpose of these methods?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are overridden in `LinkedHashMap`'s `Entry` in order to maintain its linked list of entries.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the methods serve no direct purpose. However, if you were subclassing `HashMap` you could subclass the backing `HashMap.Entry` as well to receive such events easily.

Comment: Looks like they do have a direct purpose (ref: axtavt's answer).